# Need to find duplicate record on date basis

Tags: mysql

It is not complex to find the duplicate record from one table

```
SELECT
    name, sales, date, COUNT(*)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    name, sales, date
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

However I need to find the name which was loaded yesterday but not today.

The structure of table is

```
Name,sales,date
```

And the records are loaded everyday in the morning.
and some name might do multiple sales everyday, but need to find only the name of salesmen which was there yesterday but not today

Comment: Subquery to get yesterday's salesmen left join to a subquery that gets today's salesman where today's name is null

Answer (score 2):

Self-join the table

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.name
FROM users AS u1
LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON u1.name = u2.name AND u2.date = CURDATE()
WHERE u1.date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND u2.name IS NULL
```